# Making a countdown to multiple times of day

Tags: c#

Current code:

```
        while (true)
        {
            // Gets current time
            DateTime farD = DateTime.Now;

            //Gets the departure time
            DateTime s = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(15, 30, 0);
            s = s.Date + ts;

            // Countdown to departure.
            TimeSpan apa = s-farD;

            //Writes time left and clears console. With a 1 second interval.
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2} Till färjan går",apa.Hours,apa.Minutes,apa.Seconds);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

    }
}
```

}

What I am aiming towards, is to do a countdown a specific times each day, when the ferry leaves.
Problem is that the ferry have 50+~ departure times each day, And with this solution for a countdown gets very messy.

So questions:
Is there a quicker way to make a countdown that is not dependent on what date of the month/year it is?
(Diffrent ferry times will later be controlled with DateTime.DayOfWeek)

Ill post a link with the ferry times so you can see how the times differ per time of day and weekday:
[Ferry departure times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNaf9.png)

I know Ive not come close to a final solution, but I rather want to start with the right calculation for making a countdown to a time, that is independent of what day, month or year it is.

Comment: Hi this isnt really a stack overflow question,. We do, heres my code, its not doing what it should..

Answer (score 0):

As BugFinder said, this is not stack overflow question, but i can give you a tip:

Create a **List** *AllDepartures* where you can store all departures time.

And use it:

```
List<DateTime> DayDepartures = AllDepartures.FindAll (
    o => o.DayOfWeek == DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
);
```

This is how you can get all the departures on today.
And like this you can get the departures that are after now, sorted by hour:

```
List<DateTime> NextHourDepartures = DayDepartures.FindAll (
    o => o.Hour >= DateTime.Now.Hour
).OrderBy(o => o.Hour).ToList();
```

And you can get the next departures on current hour, sorted by time like this:

```
List<DateTime> NextMinuteDepartures = NextHourDepartures.FindAll(
    o => o == NextHourDepartures[0]
).FindAll (
    o => o.Minute >= DateTime.Now.Minute
).OrderBy(o=>o.Minute).ToList();
```

and then you next departure time is:

```
DateTime nextDeparture = NextMinuteDepartures [0];
```

**Hope this helps, but next time try to represent your problem better.**